# Incrementing date by 18years in java

Tags: java, date, milliseconds, jdatechooser

1.I want to set the **setMaxSelectableDate=18years** in JDateChooser so i provided it the date by incrementing milliseconds but how should i increment it by 18years.
2.Incrementing by 18years the calculation comes out to be **365*18*24*60*60*1000=56764800000** which gives me error integer number to large.

```
 Date max=new Date();
Date oth1=new Date(max.getTime() + (365*18*24*60*60*1000));  //days*hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
SimpleDateFormat maxdateFormatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d,yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
String maxdate=maxdateFormatter1.format(oth1);  
DateChooser_V1.setMaxSelectableDate(new java.util.Date(maxdate));
```

Comment: why don't you use a long then?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a Calendar object and `cal.add(Calendar.YEAR,18);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let **[`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)** do this work for you:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(oldDate);
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 18);
Date newDate = c.getTime();
```

Which takes care of leap years, historical GMT offset changes, historical Daylight Saving Time schedule changes etc.

Comment: i accept the answer its correct but i am not able to do what i need.

Comment: @AbbyD What's the problem now?

Comment: The problem now seems different than the current question. Consider asking it as a separate question.

Comment: i declared **maxdate** at classlevel and initialized it in constructor but it gives me error **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at java.util.Date.parse(Date.java:598)**. If i declare and initialize it before constructor than it was running successfully according to my method but now due to c.setTime needs to be implemented in try{}catch{}block i moved my code in constructor and now its giving error.

Comment: its working i just pasted my code before initComponents(); the error was created because by mistake i pasted my code after initComponents();

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `long`. You can achieve this by adding an `L` to your number:

`365L* ...`

Comment: It looks better in uppercase. He meant an L :)

Comment: Use `365L` instead of `365l` so that the l does not get mistaken for a 1 as can happen in some fonts.

Comment: I agree that it looks better in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

With [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

```
DateTime in18Years = new DateTime( ).plusYears( 18 );
```

Here is how to convert to `java.util.Date`

```
Date in18Years = new DateTime( ).plusYears( 18 ).toDate( );
```

Comment: you could fit this into the OP's code by making it `Date oth1 = new DateTime().plusYears(18).toDate();`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot willy-nilly add seconds (or millseconds) and expect calendar calculations to come out right.  Basically it takes some extra effort to account for all of those leap-years, leap seconds, and daylight savings shifts.

Until Java 1.8 comes out, use `java.util.Calendar` instead of `java.util.Date`, there are *really good reasons* that `java.util.Date` has practically everything in it deprecated.  While it looks good in the beginning, with enough use you will find it often "just doesn't work (tm)".

```
 GregorianCalendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
 now.add(Calendar.YEAR, 18);
```

And that's assuming that you didn't overflow `Integer.MAX_INT`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `Calendar` object to achieve this:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date dt = new Date();
...
// Set the date value
...
cal.setTime(dt);
cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, +18);
dt = cal.getTime();
```

Hope this helps you